# Cant install any package from pip

Tags: python, selenium, pip

Every time i try to install a package with pip with the code `pip install selenium`, this error show up at the end of every attend
`ValueError:source code string cannot contain null bytes` , i try binding and nothing, please help

Comment: Which system are you on? Which python version are you using? Can you post some other info about the issue? Does the same happen if you try to install some other pip package?

Comment: my system is windows 8.1, Python version:3,9,4, and the issue happens every time i try to install a package with comand line

Comment: I would delete python entirely and reinstall

Comment: already try and nothing

Answer (score -2):

pip - It is abbreviation Python install Package. This is a package manager, use to install and manage package for Python. This command `pip install selenium`, you should write in your CLI.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc
If you use a Pycharm:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ThggxnmfrU

Comment: i am using CLI.

Comment: Maybe in your system wasn't install a Python or pip. Pleas write in your terminal `pip --version` or `pip3 --version`.

Comment: it gives me a response

Comment: Which one, `pip` or `pip3` ?

Comment: both of then give me a response, version 20.2.3

Comment: Ok. You use Windows, Mac, Linux ? I you use Linux or Mac, you try write `sudo pip install selenium`

Comment: i am using windows 8,1, Python version:3,9,4, and the issue happens every time i try to install a package with comand line

Comment: Ok. When you write in your command line `python` or `python3` what happened ?

Comment: Python version:3,9,4, and the issue happens every time i try to install a package with comand line

Comment: When you try install package in CLI what happened ? What do you see in terminal ?

Comment: a lot of things, but all attends end in `ValueError:source code string cannot contain null bytes`